# How to reproduce RNN results on several runs?

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I call same model on same input twice in a row and I don't get the same result, this model have `nn.GRU` layers so I suspect that it have some internal state that should be release before second run?

How to reset RNN hidden state to make it the same as if model was initially loaded?

**UPDATE:**

Some context:

I'm trying to run model from here:

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/models/wavernn.py#L93

I'm calling `generate`:

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/models/wavernn.py#L148

Here it's actually have some code using random generator in pytorch:

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/models/wavernn.py#L200

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/utils/distribution.py#L110

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/utils/distribution.py#L129

I have placed (I'm running code on CPU):

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(0)
```

in

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/utils/distribution.py

after all imports.

I have checked GRU weights between runs and they are the same:

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/models/wavernn.py#L153

Also I have checked `logits` and `sample` between runs and `logits` are the same but `sample` are not, so @Andrew Naguib seems were right about random seeding, but I'm not sure where the code that fixes random seed should be placed?

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/models/wavernn.py#L200

**UPDATE 2:**

I have placed seed init inside `generate` and now results are consistent:

https://github.com/erogol/WaveRNN/blob/master/models/wavernn.py#L148

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'I have placed seed init inside generate'. Can you explain that please?

Comment: @mpourreza Inside `generate` function, seems master code is changed and links are not valid anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Training PyTorch models on different machines leads to different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511658/training-pytorch-models-on-different-machines-leads-to-different-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this may be highly related to [Random Seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed). To ensure reproducible results ([as stated by them](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html)) you have to seed `torch` as in this:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
```

And also, the `CuDNN` module.

```
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

If you're using `numpy`, you could also do:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
```

However, they warn you:

> Deterministic mode can have a performance impact, depending on your model.

---

A suggested script I regularly use which has been working very good to reproduce results is:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import random
import torch
# ...
""" Set Random Seed """
if args.random_seed is not None:
    """Following seeding lines of code are to ensure reproducible results 
       Seeding the two pseudorandom number generators involved in PyTorch"""
    random.seed(args.random_seed)
    np.random.seed(args.random_seed)
    torch.manual_seed(args.random_seed)
    # https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/randomness.html#cudnn
    if not args.cpu_only:
        torch.cuda.manual_seed(args.random_seed)
        cudnn.deterministic = True
        cudnn.benchmark = False
```

Comment: My problem that 2 consecutive calls of model on same data is producing different results, if I run it two separate times I get same results.

Comment: Updated initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.init_hidden()` to reset the RNN hidden state.

```
def init_hidden(self):
     # Initialize hidden and cell states
     return Variable(torch.zeros(num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size))
```

So, before calling the same model on the same data next time, you can call model.init_hidden() to reset the hidden and cell states to the initial values.

This will clear out the history, in order words, the weights the model learned after running on the data first time.

Comment: What is the type of model should be? class derived from `nn.Module`?